# How to open data instead standart url in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, video, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

How i can open data video file instead standart url in AVPlayer?

```
let videoURL = URL(string: "https://example")
```

but instead URL i have only

```
var dataTs : Data = Data()
```

and i must put it in AVPlayerController

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
playerViewController.player = player
```

Comment: write your data to a temporary url

Comment: @LeoDabus i have only dataTs in Data format how i can write your data to a temporary url ?

Comment: Create a url at a temporary location `let fileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("video.ext")`

Comment: and write your data to it. If you would like to overwrite the file if it already exists use options .atomic: `do {
    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}`

Comment: and after put this url to here? let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)

Comment: Yes just use the fileURL as you wish

Comment: If you would like to your video persist between launches you will need to save it to a regular folder inside your App Sandbox like the documentDirectory or if you don't want the user to have access to it you can save it to your app library folder. For more info about where to store your app files check the File System Programming Guide  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the data to a temporary file. You can use a named pipe instead. It's very similar to writing to a temporary file, except that it doesn't require any storage space and it's faster.

If you're not familiar with named pipes, they aren't that complex. They look like and act like files, but rather than the data from the file coming from storage media, it's coming from another process or thread. They're created with a simple function call that looks like this in Swift:

```
mkfifo("foo", 0o666) // Note: 0o666 is Swift notation for octal values
```

Here's how it would work in your case: You create the named pipe as shown above. Then you setup a dispatch queue to open the file and write your data to it. The write operation will block until something else comes along and opens the same file to read from it. When that happens, your write operation will unblock and start sending data directly to the incoming read request.

Once your dispatch is setup and waiting, just continue along like normal and pass in a `URL` that points to your named pipe to `AVPlayer`. `AVPlayer` will think it's reading from a file, but it's really reading the data from your `dataTs` object.

You can get a basic working version with a single helper function that essentially converts a `Data` object into a `URL` for one-time use. Here's a Swift sample:

```
func setupNamedPipe(withData data: Data) -> URL?
{
    // Build a URL for a named pipe in the documents directory
    let fifoBaseName = "avpipe"
    let fifoUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!.appendingPathComponent(fifoBaseName)

    // Ensure there aren't any remnants of the fifo from a previous run
    unlink(fifoUrl.path)

    // Create the FIFO pipe
    if mkfifo(fifoUrl.path, 0o666) != 0
    {
        print("Failed to create named pipe")
        return nil
    }

    // Run the code to manage the pipe on a dispatch queue
    DispatchQueue.global().async
    {
        print("Waiting for somebody to read...")
        let fd = open(fifoUrl.path, O_WRONLY)
        if fd != -1
        {
            print("Somebody is trying to read, writing data on the pipe")
            data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
                let num = write(fd, bytes, data.count)
                if num != data.count
                {
                    print("Write error")
                }
            }

            print("Closing the write side of the pipe")
            close(fd)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Failed to open named pipe for write")
        }

        print("Cleaning up the named pipe")
        unlink(fifoUrl.path)
    }

    return fifoUrl
}
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
var dataTs : Data = Data() // ...your data...

if let videoURL = setupNamedPipe(withData: dataTs)
{
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    playerViewController.player = player

    // ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: i try implement this function but video still not playing 
from func that print ("Waiting for somebody to read...") and "Somebody is trying to read, writing data on the pipe"
but load indicator never stop

Comment: maybe they can not run .ts file

Comment: or better convert .tv to .mp4 but i not sure solution on Swift

Comment: Hi im getting the error responds, "Permission denied". You could solve the isssue? Please share me if any correction required.

Comment: @pauln data.withUnsafeBytes is called just once and video isn't played.